# Spring boot session in redis, expiration time update for each access

Tags: spring, spring-boot, spring-security, redis, spring-session

Am using the redis to hold the sessions for Spring boot application, as from the documentation i can see like, expiration time will be set for each key created in redis.

But whether the expiration time value will be updated on each access from spring, i.e on accessing for subsequent requests from browser. My question is whether the expiration time will be reset on subsequent access or it will remain the same as created, if yes, then the user may get an error while using the application for long time.

Any help/suggestions on this?

Comment: Expiry in redis works this way. Lets say you put a key in redis with expiry as 1 hour. The key won't be available after 1 hour from the time it got inserted in the redis. It won't get updated each time if we just access the key.

Comment: @BalajiSrinivasan Does this mean that if I touch the key again, its TTL will go back to its initial value?